# Macro wont run for all users

Tags: excel, vba

The error occurs on 
    Set report = app.OpenReport("S:\Supply Chain\Scheduling\HRE\HRE.imr")
It works for some users and not others.
Any alternative methods or maybe some settings that need to be changed?
Its an objected defined error.

```
`Sub Update()

Dim app As Object
Dim report As Object
Dim catalog As Object

'open cognos'

Set app = CreateObject("CognosImpromptu.Application")
app.Visible True
app.Activate

'open catalog'

app.OpenCatalog "R:CognosUsers/Cognos Catalogs/SUPPLY CHAIN.cat"
app.Visible True
app.Activate

'open report'

Set report = app.OpenReport("S:\Supply Chain\Scheduling\HRE\HRE.imr")
report.RetrieveAll

'save report path'

report.Export "S:\Supply Chain\Scheduling\HRE\Raw", "X_ascii.flt"
'close cognos'
report.CloseReport
app.Quit`
```

Comment: Are there mounted network drive ?

Comment: Use `If Dir("R:CognosUsers/Cognos Catalogs/SUPPLY CHAIN.cat") = vbNullString Then MsgBox "File not found!" : Exit Sub` to validate the path before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already looked at this, but the first thing I would check is (1) if the R:\ and S:\ are properly mapped (if you click on the R:\ and S:\ in the file explorer, does it take you where you would expect?); (2) that the user has access to the various folders/files/applications in the code.